# How can pass data to server and page redirected to next content page as my control and data is from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have taken five dropdown lists in master page and one Imagebutton.
On click of Image button values of dropdown list are passed to server side for processing and result will be displayed on another content page.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `Session` Variables like shown below:

First initiate Session variable with values

```
Session["variablename"] = value //can be int, string, datatable, array etc
```

Use on other page

```
getvalue = Session["variablename"].ToString() //if the value is string type (or convert it accordingly)
```

If use of `Session` Variable are over then dump it.

```
Session.Remove("variablename");
```